# Using Python3 or Bash, how can I send ctrl+a d to my program?

Tags: bash, python-3.x, gnu-screen

I know this question has been asked a few times, and the answer that I have seen is `screen -m -d`.

What seems to separate my situation is that I'm trying to have tcpdump running in that screen, and when I combine tcpdump with `-m -d`, tcpdump never runs. It works with something like `touch` which I've seen used as an example in an answer, so it seems that I'm on the right track.

The solution I'm envisioning would have the screen open, tcpdump begins to run, and then I send ctrl+a d to the screen session so that it can continue to run for as long as the user desires.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Don't attach the session in the first place, and you won't need to detach from it after starting `tcpdump`.

Comment: This is the very definition of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- you want to do one thing (start a program in screen without attaching to it), but you're asking how to do something different (send a key sequence as if it were entered by a user).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Perhaps I explained it poorly. I meant I wanted to attach, start tcpdump, and exit the screen so the script can continue to run more things. We want tcpdump to run for a week, so I can't wait for it to be done to continue things if I want the script to complete in a timely manner.

Comment: @BryanMooney But you don't *need* to attach; the only reason you need to send ctrl+a d is that you unnecessarily attached to the session to run the command.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-d -m` when you start `screen` to avoid attaching to it in the first place:

```
screen -d -m tcpdump
```